# Can i instantiate an object without methods?

Tags: java, syntax-error

I'm very very new to coding and learning the concepts of OOPs. Please treat the question in that regard. I'm expecting down-votes but need explanations so posting here.

This is my code snippet, I'm creating an object and calling a method with it, but the error comes as - Syntax error on token "login", Identifier expected after this token

What am I doing wrong?

```
public class testabb {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }

    public static void login() {
         System.out.println("Login");   
    }

    testabb t = new testabb();
    t.login();

}
```

Comment: You can't call methods in the body of a class. Move your last 2 lines inside the main method.

Comment: You can't have arbitrary code directly inside the class. Only field declarations, constructors, methods, initialization blocks.

Comment: The code fragment you have there must be inside a code block like a method body. Currently it is on the `class` level, where it shouldn't be. Put the code in a method, like your empty `main()` method.

Comment: Thank you, I moved it to main method and it worked like a charm. Now if i create another method and then move the code there, I guess I need to call that new method also from main to work??

public class testabb {
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
 }
 
 public static void login() {
  System.out.println("Login"); 
 }
 
 
 public static void anothermethod() {
  
  testabb t = new testabb();
  t.login();
   
 }

Comment: Note: Assuming your method name is a command, the capitalization should be `logIn`, or `doLogin`, rather than `login`; "log in" is the verb; "login" is the noun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just have code floating around directly under a class - it should be in a method, constructor or an initializer block. E.g.:

```
public class testabb {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testabb t = new testabb();
        t.login();
    }

    public static void login() {
         System.out.println("Login");   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a method using your object outside a method. You can't do that in your program. Here, you should call it inside a method but only after the instantiation i.e you have to instantiate the object before the control goes to the call statement. Here I have called it inside main method after the instantiation.

```
public class testabb {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        testabb t = new testabb();
        t.login();
    }

    public static void login() {
        System.out.println("Login");    
    }
}
```